# High CPU consumption when deleting RabbitMQ Queue?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I have a problem on RabbitMQ where in whenever I delete a queue the CPU goes up. The more I delete a rabbit queue the CPU gradually increases. It seems to me that at some point there is some object that is not ended. By the way on my code there was no loop just plain QueueDelete.
I'm using RabbitMQ .net library.

Please let me know if you have encountered this kind of problem and how did you fixed it. Or any suggestions will do.

Best regards,

Comment: High CPU is in and of itself is not a problem. You have a CPU, it is intended to be used, right?  Now, the question is; is it causing *an appreciable problem in your application*?

Comment: Yes it is. It really is a big deal. The CPU goes up 100% on my i3 processor. And all that consumes it is my application. My application does the creation and deletion of rabbit queues. 5 deletion of queues is enough to make it upto 70-80%.

Comment: Ok, well, time to break out a profiler then.

Comment: I did a profiling and the heat is on [clr.dll] from RabbitMQ.Util.SharedQueue.Dequeue()

Comment: It's going to be tough then as I assume you do not have the source code for this library.  Can you contact their support team?

Comment: I am seeing the problem more and more clearer now. So the problem really is not about deleting the Rabbit Queue. So this is what happened. I create queue dynamically whenever someone request for it. Whenever I create it I also need to consume from that queue. And to do that I have a delegateMethod . Whenever request for delete queue comes in the delegateMethod or the thread is not stopped and keeps working on. Now my problem is how to remove that thread.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by checking channels and consumers if they are still running.

So on my consume method, before I get the message, I am checking if the channel is still open and or the consumer tag is still running. This way I know what to do if this returns true. What happened on my previous code was I don't have checking and exceptions was not handled. So every time I delete a channel it is throwing an exception on consume.

Thanks